# determine if a string is made up of only certain characters

Tags: java, string

So I want to be able to determine if a string is made up of only a certain characters.

Say I want to see if a string is made up of only `a,b,c` how would I do that

Example of strings that would work are
`a,aaaa,abc,cc,abc,cba` ect

any help would be awesome

Comment: You can use a RegEx for this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include what you've tried.

Comment: Loop through the string, checking character by character for if that character is in the list. If it isn't, return false.

Comment: @JamesWilliams thats pretty inefficient though isnt it?

Comment: I Agree with @iajrz. A RegEx is probably the most straight forward way. But since he said it first, my comment is that as a string is a CharSequence, you could also loop through each character searching if each character is in the list of allowed characters.

Comment: Possibly, but it is a place to start.

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean containsOnly(String str, String certain){
    return str.matches("[" + certain + "]*");
}
```

This will match an empty string always, if you wish to change that, just change the `*` to `+`.

This uses regexs and pretty simple. The logic isn't laid out fully though. Basically, it makes sure that the string matches any combination of the characters in 'certain'.

```
containsOnly("aaaa", "abc") -> True
containsOnly("abca", "abc") -> True
containsOnle("aaaz", "abc") -> False
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache `StringUtils` to the rescue - [http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsOnly(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsOnly%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean onlyCertainCharacters(String str, String certainCharacters)
{
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) //Check each character in the String
    {
        if(certainCharacters.indexOf(str.substr(i,1))==-1) //Return false if the character isn't in the list of allowed characters
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; //If we haven't returned yet, then all characters must match
}
```

Usage:

```
onlyCertainCharacters("aaaa,"abc") //==true
onlyCertainCharacters("aaad,"abc") //==false
```

Of course, you could just use regex, but that's not as much fun.

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you if you have an offending character.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatch {
    private static void match(String REGEX, String INPUT) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
        int count = 0;

        while (m.find()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("\nMatch number: " + count);
            System.out.println("start() : " + m.start());
            System.out.println("end()   : " + m.end());
            System.out.println("group() : " + m.group());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        match("[^abc]", "zbc");
    }
}
```